# Listings (Lisp) and the > symbol

Tags: listings

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Lisp,
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{keywordcolor},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{stringcolor},
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle=\texttt}
\begin{lstlisting}
(> 3 2)
(a 3 2)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Notice how the ">" symbol is much larger in this output than it is, say, in the latex file just above. Is there a way to say "just give me the one that looks like it's in the same font as all the other characters in this font"?  (Now that I look at it, the numbers seem to be in a different font as well -- less "Courier"-like than I'd expect.)

Comment: Isn't it easier to do `basicstyle=\ttfamily` than repeating it for every part?

Comment: It surely is...but that would have required that I read the whole"listings" doc rather than just editing what someone else had already done. :) Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion it's easier to do `basicstyle=\ttfamily` than repeating the declaration for each part of the language.

However, you can do it in an indirect way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand{\ttgt}{\texttt{\char`\>}}

\lstset{
  language=Lisp,
  keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{keywordcolor},
  stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{stringcolor},
  commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{commentcolor},
  identifierstyle=\texttt,
  literate={>}{\ttgt}1,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
(> 3 2)
(a 3 2)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Not sure why preferring numbers in normal font. Here's the other approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=Lisp,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
(> 3 2)
(a 3 2)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a typewriter font that has a nice `>`, i.e. [Source Code Pro](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/sourcecodepro/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[default]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=Lisp,
    keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{keywordcolor},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily\color{stringcolor},
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\color{commentcolor},
    identifierstyle=\texttt}
\begin{lstlisting}
(> 3 2)
(a 3 2)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]